# Rails radio button param is a string instead of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, forms

Form:

```
<%= form_for :computer do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :state, value: 'on' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :state, value: 'off' %>
<% end %>
```

Outputs:

```
params[:computer][:state]
{:value=>"on"}

params[:computer][:state].class
String

params[:computer][:state][:value]
No implicit conversion of string into integer

params[:computer][:state]['value']
value
```

No, there is no .to_s anywhere! :)

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835987/expecting-params-hash-but-getting-a-string-rails), but it's been unanswered since 2011 and is for a different version of rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper usage of `radio_button` in your case is the following:

```
f.radio_button :state, 'on'
```

The second argument is the value to pass when selected, you don't need the key/value pair `value: 'on'` there.

It will end up mapping the value in `params[:computer][:state]`

Comment: omg, [wrong version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060268/how-to-use-radio-button-correctly-in-rails)! i'm guessing this is going to become more and more of a problem for the stupid like me as the years pass and pages accumulate.

Comment: it is good to always take a look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/, append at the end of the url the Rails version you're working on like `v5.0.7/`, in this case https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.7/, and you'll get the documentation for that version. There you can see the syntax you should be using.